# Is it possible to change the emission rate of particles over time?

Tags: animation, particles

Is it possible to change the emission rate of particles over time?

E.g. Start off with an initial burst of particles, then emit at a steady rate.

Here is a (poor) example of what I mean by the emission rate:

[image]

Is this possible to do using only one particle system? (This is necessary because the particles are being used to emit smoke)

---

The gif above was made by manually sliding the *End* value, but it gives strange and unpredictable results (as can be seen in the gif) as well as not being keyframeable.

Comment: Have you tried setting keyframes for the _Number_ of particles? / Nevermind that does not work

Comment: Why not use two meshes? One with the original burst of smoke and one with the constant flow? i.e. http://puu.sh/56vKJ.png (I'll post an answer if it's what you want)

Comment: @CharlesL I thought of that, it certainty would work, but it struck me as something that you should be able to do in one particle system. Post if you want, but just note that I'm looking for an answer that does this in one mesh/particle system first :)

Comment: I tried using a color ramp to affect the density and animate the color of that (black being low density and white being full), but it doesn't seem to work at all :/ But the particle code is all a big mess from what I hear, so we can only hope for Lukas to finish his work.

Comment: I've definitely run into situations where I'd much rather specify the number of particles per second, rather than the total number of particles. This is relevant to my interests.

Comment: LOL Is this a joke? You cannot animate the Particles Number in Emission, that would provide an off-going? Instead have to make different Particle Systems with different Frame Start Ends. Thats ridicilous lol

Comment: @Gordon1fm Hopefully for not much longer; there's a new system for particle simulation [in development](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/103032). If you want a taste of what will be possible, you could check out [the system which was briefly introduced in blender 2.9 and later removed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jtEh1JT8pY4). It was removed to focus on geometry nodes, and the new system is planned to be integrated with geometry nodes to allow even greater flexibility.

Comment: If you're feeling adventurous (or desperate!) you *might* be able to make something work with the [animation nodes addon](http://animation-nodes.com/). To be clear I have not used it myself, but I do see simulation nodes mentioned in [this unofficial experimental build](https://blender.community/c/graphicall/0hbbbc/)

Comment: Thx for the links. The inbuild particle system is actually pretty easy and fast to use. But I never expected to not have the possibility to animate the emission rate. As it is just essential xD Can't believe it actually. It just logical to actually have emission rate. I will wait. This animation nodes addon is pretty outdated. But interesting to see such big addons exist for blender.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**In short, there's no ready solution.** Lukas Tönne was responsible for a feature known as "Paged Buffers for Particles" but at some point he stopped working on it and the feature never made it to trunk. Here's a timeline of what happened:

- March 11 2011: [This video shows that variable particle emission was working.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_v3KfwdMaA)
- March 17 2011: [Paged Buffers for Particles research](http://code.blender.org/index.php/2011/03/paged-buffers-for-particles/) was published on Blender's developer blog.
- July 22 2011: A crowd-funding campaign launched through Lukas's blog.
- Dec 6 2011: [Lukas spoke about his progress at the 2011 Blender Conference.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7WHxmdoWBrU)
- May 4 2012: [Last blog post on the subject.](http://phonybone.planetblender.org/2012/05/04/video-update/)
- August 4 2013: [Lukas was hired to do general bug fixing with the Blender Foundation.](http://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-committers/2013-August/041418.html) His work would be "especially for nodes and [the] compositor. When time allows, he then can also pick up work on new particle system."
- August 26 2013: [In episode 26 of the Blender Podcast](http://blender-podcast.org/?p=541), Lukas stated "I started working on the particles, but there are a few basic issues that need to be fixed on a more general level before I can go into the details of node-ifying particles and things like that."
- 2014–Present: [His tweets about node development](https://twitter.com/search?q=nodes%20from%3Alukastoenne%20since%3A2013-01-01) continue to mention relevant subject matter including duplis which will eventually feed into particle nodes.
- Nov 1, 2015: [B2.8 project developer kickoff meeting notes](http://code.blender.org/2015/11/the-2-8-project-for-developers/) mentions that "The particle system and constraints may need a complete overhaul."

Answer (score 3):

This technique isn't exactly what you asked for but it could simulate. In particle settings, "die on hit" is active and there is a hidden grid type object keyframed moving through the scene as a collision object.
http://youtu.be/-LkoZbOchfo

Comment: This works. Here's another riff on "Die on hit".  Easier to control. Two collision objects offset to open and allow particles through as keyframed.  http://youtu.be/2IoroZF1iYY

Answer (score 3):

If it is acceptable for the "burst-particles" to disappear once you change emission rates, Keyframing the Children settings in Particles might approach what you are hoping for. For a binary on/off effect, keyframe the red-starred section in the image below; to modulate linearly, keyframe the yellow-starred section.

[image: Particle Children Settings]
[image: Particle Burst]

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) Interesting idea, though I would rather that particles do not die before their time..

Answer (score 1):

I know this is way old and there's a new particle system and geometry nodes and probably better ways of doing this, but I didn't find them easily.

I did find that animating the scale of the emitter worked. There's an obvious need to control where the particles go if you do this, and it might not work in all cases, but it's something. . .