# Animation - Falling object one after the other

Tags: animation

I like to animate a larger Number of boxes, falling or better moving straight from out of the camera view on a surface, one after the other. Starting slow and become faster to the end of the animation. It is just a straight linear move, up to down. No tumbling or anything else. Each box should be placed in the same way next to the box before.

Has somebody a tip how to do it in a proper way? Or is there a faster way then keyframing every object seperatly?
Help or some tips would be great! Thank you guys.

Comment: Are the boxes tumbling after impacting a surface or just moving in a straight line or something else?  Please clarify in your question.

Comment: possibly related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3560/is-it-possible-to-change-the-emission-rate-of-particles-over-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

A particle system drops cubes onto a collision barrier.  Please excuse the poor quality gif.  The file size is too small.

Settings below.

[image]

In the image above are the particle system settings.  The settings occupy two panes.  The emitter is moving at constant speed. Linear curve.  No acceleration.  Click to see details.

The floor is a black plane.  Black is beautiful.  The plane is a Physics Collision Object and its settings are on the far right.  Note the settings are pinned so that we can view properties of multiple objects.

Note the particle count <<< than the number of frames.

This is not a tutorial on creating particle systems.  You may search here at BSE or the famous website that rhymes with noonoob.