# Simulation of objects falling one after another

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

I would like to animate a great number of Cubes, falling from a plane located in a determined height, one after another. Each cube should be placed close to the cube placed before.

What I've want to do is deploying a sort kind of barrier (in several horizontal layers). To simulate the real life implementation I simply moved one element higher than the other, but in this way (obviously) the simulation gets affected by the gravity. I know how to through the element at steady speed, but it could be more realistic if each element appears after that the previous one has already reached the ground (it should be simulate a "crane" that places these elements on the building site).

Has somebody advices how to do it?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: do you want to use physic or not?

Comment: any suggested idea is welcome

Comment: so maybe take a look at a basic tutorial about cube falling on a plane with Physics, the cube are Rigid Body > Active, the plane is Rigid Body > Passive

Comment: do all cubes need to be there at the beginning? maybe you could toy around with a particle emitter.

Comment: no they don't; the particle emitter could be a good idea, but how can "emit" cubes instead of particles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want to test physics, here what you could try:

- Create 3 objects, a cube, a funnel, a plane.

[image]

- Make your funnel and plane *Rigid Bodies*, *Type* > *Passive* (they are obstacles), *Shape* > *Mesh* (the topology will be taken into account).

[image]

- Make the cube a *Rigid Body*, *Type* > *Active* (it will fall), *Shape* > *Mesh* (not necessary in that case I guess). Duplicate the cube. If all your cubes are ready and different, just give the *Rigid Body* to one of them, select all, then the one with *Rigid Body* and in 2.8, *Object* > *Rigid Body* > *Copy From Active* (in 2.7, *T* panel > *Physics* > *Copy From Active*).

[image]

- Start the animation, the cubes fall.

[image]

- If you want to keep them close to each others, create a *Force Field* > *Force* with a negative *Strength*.

[image]

Comment: thanks, but actually I want to place them in order to create a sort-kind of grid, like a barrier

Comment: ok so maybe edit your question to give a full explanation of what you want, maybe show a drawing etc...

Comment: I attached the .blend file; what I've want to do is deploying a sort kind of barrier (in several horizontal layers). To simulate the real life implementation I simply moved one element higher than the other, but in this way (obviously) the simulation gets affected by the gravity. I know how to through the element at steady speed, but it could be more realistic if each element appears after that the previous one has already reached the ground (it should be simulate a "crane" that places this elements on the building site)

Comment: ok I'll try to find a solution when I'll have time, maybe don't mark my answer as good so that someone else has the curiosity to check your question  ;)

Comment: great, thanks!!

Comment: so you want each cube to fall on each other? with a small bouncy effect when they hit? or no physical effect at all? but they don't fall, they just stack up?

Comment: Sorry it's not easy to understand, if you don't want Physics, have you tried just to move your object from position A (top) to B (bottom)? If you want to use Physics, maybe use some invisible narrow funnels so that each cube ends precisely on the previous one? If you have a lot of cube it might be the solution, you'd avoid tedious animations... Just suggestions, I'm not sure it's what you want...

Comment: Also invisible narrow funnels could be an idea. But what I was searching for, is a method like explained in this link, probably I should use the particle emitter; but how can I do this using a Cube and not particles? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60865/animation-falling-object-one-after-the-other

Comment: Your emitted objects can be whatever you want, so yes it might be the solution, except your cubes bottom doesn't seem flat so I don't know how you'll make them stack up, that's why I was talking about funnel that ends as narrow pipes so that it creates stack. You could also look into Animation Nodes, but it's a bit complicated for me.

Comment: yeah it's not properly a cube, it has some protrusions; thanks for the help!

Comment: also you could use cubes following path with various offsets, maybe a bit tedious though

Comment: mmmh doesn't seem easy to do with Physics, the cubes jam in the pipe...