# Particle Emission Rate?

Tags: particles

By default in Blender, you set the emission of particles by specifying a starting frame, an ending frame, how many particles you want to spawn during this time, and how long you want each particle to live for.

This is fine and all, but it would be incredibly useful if instead you could simply state how many particles per frame you would like to spawn, and to have that carry on for as long as you want without having to constantly adjust the start/end frame and particle density.

Is this currently possible in Blender? If so, how is it accomplished?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the emission rate of particles over time?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3560/is-it-possible-to-change-the-emission-rate-of-particles-over-time)

Answer (score 3):

with the new particle system in blender 2.9 alpha this solves my problem

Comment: How? Could you please explain?

Answer (score 1):

I just asked this question seems like it still hasn't changed only hope I can offer is this "The particle system and constraints may need a complete overhaul." quoted from the 2.8 developer notes from 2015 (rip) https://code.blender.org/2015/11/the-2-8-project-for-developers/

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've found around this is to put a plane in front of the emitter with 'Die on Hit' and animate its position to allow particles through.

I certainly hope this gets some attention because the particle system is one of Blenders' weaknesses.

A compete rewrite with node control would be awesome.

Comment: I'm finding Blender very impressive otherwise