# Particle system animated emission speed

Tags: particles

How can I have a particle system emit few particles at first, then more particles, then less particles again?

I am using a particle system for rain that rains a little at first (rain drizzle), then slowly increases to a lot later (rain showers), then slowly stops.

| axis label | rain/particle emission distribution |
| --- | --- |
| amount of particles emitted | [image] |
|  | time |

[The linked question "Is it possible to change the emission rate of particles over time?"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3560/is-it-possible-to-change-the-emission-rate-of-particles-over-time)'s answers are all nearly 10 years old, and does not create acceptable emission rate.

Particle system emissions are in terms of emission over frame range (not emission rate), and is not an animatable property.

Comment: the particle system itself cannot do that, but...one workaround would be to use a mesh directly in front of the emitter with a lot of small holes and maybe scale that (keyframes on scale) and give it collision and the particles system check "die on hit" so it will let less through.